# Unsure if I'm writing my higher order components correctly

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

In the React app I'm working on, I am wrapping various components in HOC's I've written to do things like check for authentication. I am wondering if the way I'm doing it is a good or bad practice. The HOC's work just as expected, but I'm wondering if perhaps I'm doing something that isn't very good. Here's an example:
If the user goes to /profile, the component `ProfilePage.js` is rendered:

```
import React from 'react';
import Profile from './Profile';
import withLogin from './hoc/withLogin';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export const ProfilePage = props => <div> <Profile /> </div>

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => ({ auth });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withLogin(ProfilePage));
```

This is `Profile.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ProfileForm from './ProfileForm';
export const Profile = props => {
    const render = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Profile component</h1>
                <ProfileForm />
            </div>
        );
    };
    return <div>{render()}</div>;
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => ({ auth });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profile);
```

Here is my `withLogin.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import RequireLogin from './RequireLogin';

export default () => Component => <RequireLogin component={Component} />;
```

, and here is `RequireLogin.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Loading from '../Loading';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const RequireLogin = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    switch (rest.auth) {
        case null:
            return <Loading />;
        case false:
            return <Redirect to='/' />;
        default:
            return <Component />;
    }
};
const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => ({ auth });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RequireLogin);
```

EDIT: It seems I did not spend enough time looking into this testing issue. My `withLogin` function returns a component, so I needed to shallow render it in the test cases. Like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import withLogin from '../withLogin';

test('withLogin renders RequireLogin', () => {
    const MyComponent = () => <div>myComponent</div>;
    const Wrapped = withLogin(MyComponent);
    const wrapper = shallow(<Wrapped />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

This snapshot returns what I expect.
I still have questions regarding the best practices regarding the higher order components though.

I do fear this question might be getting a little too long now, but there is another issue I thing might be connected if I am indeed doing something wrong with my HOCs: I am having much difficulty testing them with Jest.
The test file for my `withLogin.js` file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import withLogin from '../withLogin';

test('withLogin renders RequireLogin', () => {
    const myComponent = () => <div>Component</div>;
    const wrapper = withLogin(myComponent);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

but the snapshot only returns this:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`withLogin renders RequireLogin 1`] = `[Function]`; //Here i would expect to see an instance of <RequireLogin />
```

My test file for `RequireLogin.js` looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { RequireLogin } from '../RequireLogin';
import users from '../../../fixtures/users';
test('RequireLogin renders <Loading /> if auth is null', () => {
    const wrappedComponent = <div>wrappedComponent</div>;
    const wrapper = shallow(<RequireLogin auth={null} component={wrappedComponent} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});

test('RequireLogin renders <Redirect to="/profile" /> if auth is false', () => {
    const wrappedComponent = <div>wrappedComponent</div>;
    const wrapper = shallow(<RequireLogin auth={false} component={wrappedComponent} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});

test('RequireLogin renders <Component /> if auth is valid', () => {
    const wrappedComponent = <div>wrappedComponent</div>;
    const wrapper = shallow(<RequireLogin auth={users[0]} component={wrappedComponent} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

but the snapshot returns this:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`RequireLogin renders <Component /> if auth is valid 1`] = `<[object Object] />`; //Here i would expect <Component />

exports[`RequireLogin renders <Loading /> if auth is null 1`] = `<Loading />`;

exports[`RequireLogin renders <Redirect to="/profile" /> if auth is false 1`] = `
<Redirect
  push={false}
  to="/"
/>
`;
```

All the snapshot tests for all of my other components are working as expected. I suspect it might have done something to do with the `RequireLogin` component being connected to my Redux store, but I don't mock the store in the test files? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you turn your HOCs which look fine btw to render props. 
There are many advantages of doing so. Example: since render props Composition patten compose at run time you do not have to worry about name space collision oppose to HOCs which compose at compile time.
There other benefits as well, read below
Read : https://reactrocket.com/post/turn-your-hocs-into-render-prop-components/
Or
Read: https://cdb.reacttraining.com/use-a-render-prop-50de598f11ce
to find out other benefits over HOCs